# Do African wild dogs have sharper teeth than domesticated dogs?

Tags: teeth, dogs

When I see African wild dogs hunting it appears easy for them to tear open their prey, whereas when a dog like a pitbull terrier bites a wild animal it looks like more of a just bite crush or puncture wound.  Do wild dogs have some sort of teeth that can tear their prey open?